# Is it possible to create std future with blocking destructor without calling std async?

Tags: c++, asynchronous

There is a remark on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/%7Efuture) about the destructor of `std::future` that it will block:

> it may block if all of the following are true: the shared state was created by a call to std::async, the shared state is not yet ready, and this was the last reference to the shared state.

So, basically if I create future via `promise.get_future()`, it does not block in destructor.

Is there a way to create an `std::future` with blocking destructor from `std::promise`?

---

Universal Asynchronous Model provides the means to customize behavior of asynchronous methods.
For instance, a completion may be a callable object, which may be a lambda:

```
async_foo([](){ std::cout << "foo";});
std::cout << "bar";
```

This will provide `barfoo`

You can also use a future to get synchronization primitives like `std::future`.

```
async_foo(asio::use_future);
std::cout << "bar"; // this line should be invoked only after async_foo has been completed
```

However, this does not work, since `std::future` will not block like it will in:

```
std::async(std::launch::async, &foo);
std::cout << "bar"; // this line will be invoked only after async foo has been completed
```

Comment: your are quoting incorrectly. The original text says "these actions will not block for the shared state..." where "this actions" refer to the bullet points above

Comment: I'm more curious about why you need the destructor to be blocking. What problem is that supposed to solve? Perhaps that problem could be solved in another way?

Comment: It sounds like you want it to block, always. The quote says it *may* block which is no guarantee. So I would look at another solution altogether.

Comment: ...though I have to admit, I don't understand what is written on cppref. To me it looks like a poor translation of the actual text in the standard.

Comment: this is the part in the standard: https://eel.is/c++draft/futures#state-5. Note that it is not about destructor of `future` specifically, but about "shared state". I still think the cppref entry isnt one of the best and the three bullets are a little confusing in that context

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I don't see any difference in that part of the standard. It is exactly the same: *if all of the following are true*. So if the future was not created by `std::async`, it will not block.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude when you implement an asynchronous method according to Universal Asynchronous Model (like in asio), you may return a future. This is convenient, if you need an asynchronous method to behave like synchronous. That is `async_foo(asio::use_future)` will block until returned xvalue `std::future` is not unblocked within its destructor.

Comment: The difference is that the original text is more general, because it describes what happens when shared state is released. Anyhow, I just noticed that you quoted wrongly and wanted to know what it is actually about. The big quesiton is still, why do you want to have a blocking destructor? Can you show some code example where this would matter?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number read my comment above to Someprogrammerdude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a light wrapper for the `std::future`.

```
#include <future>

template <typename T>
class MyBlockingFuture {
    std::future<T> future;

    public:
    MyBlockingFuture(std::future<T>&& f) : future(std::move(f)) {}
    ~MyBlockingFuture() {
        if (future.valid()) {
            future.wait();
        }
    }
};
```

Then add whatever get or wait methods you need.

---

Making `std::future` behave this way is not possible without modifying it.

Also note that there is no guarantee that the shared state held by a promise from `std::async` will block when destructed. The note only says that it *may* do so.

Comment: this is an obvious solution, but the question is explicitly about the possibility of creating `std::future`

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik So your question is about how to change the behaviour of a standard library class... ?

Comment: no, my question about the possibility. The answe may be *no, it is not possible*

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik Then the answer is no. It's not possible. FYI your assumptions about order of operations after your edit are incorrect. Both the first and last example can result in both `barfoo` and `foobar`. As I already pointed out in my comment, the fact that a future *may* block doesn't guarantee that it will.

Comment: if you update your answer with the *it's not possible*, I will accept it

Answer (score 0):

Blocking a future in a destructor is pretty fraught with danger in the first place, since it can throw an exception.

However even if that's not really your question, in case someone else lands here, it's fairly easy to write a wrapper that would do just that.

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct FutureWaiter {
    ~FutureWaiter () { fut_.wait(); }

    std::future<T>& fut_;
};

template<typename T>
[[nodiscard]] FutureWaiter<T> scoped_wait(std::future<T>& fut) {
    return FutureWaiter<T>{fut};
}

int main() {
  std::promise<int> x;
  auto fut = x.get_future();

  auto wait = scoped_wait(fut);
 
  x.set_value(3);
}
```

You may want/need to change the ownership semantics a bit depending on your needs, but the principles should remain the same.